# Took is having a different value than the time ES is taking to show the result in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a query in Elastic Search which is fetching 10000 records having approximately 8MB of data. In the "took" tag in the JSON response, it is showing "1071" meaning 1071 ms. However the response is actually appearing in Kibana after approximately, 6 to 7 seconds later. Same thing is observed, when I am executing it from JAVA API. After doing some googling, I understood that "took" includes only the query execution time in Elastic Search later and does not include the time for the following:

1) Sending the response to the server

2) Deserializing the request from JSON on the server

3) Serializing the response into JSON on the server

4) Sending the response over the network

So, given the above scenario, what measures can I take to make sure that it appears in a very reasonable time (in 1 or 2 seconds)?

Comment: Can you specify which version of the ES are you using. When you specified JAVA API, what  is the jar version and how are you communicating with the ES, whcih API in particular? 8MB is the size of compressed data or the actual one?

Comment: @ShankarDaruga, The ES version is 5.4.1 I am using JestClient API for connecting to the ES sever. JestClient version is 5.3.4 The data I am telling is created when I am getting the response in a file through `curl` command. So this is not compressed data.